# $p=2^n+3$ prime $\implies$ $(p\bmod3)=2\;$ or $(p\bmod5)\in\{2,3,4\}$?

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic

Let $n$ be such that $p=2^n+3$ is prime (see [A057732](https://oeis.org/A057732)).

Does it hold at least one of $\gcd(3,p-1)=1$ or $\gcd(5,p-1)=1$, which is equivalent to the proposition in title?

Motivation is construction of a permutation over $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ as $m\mapsto m^e\bmod p$ for one of $e=3$ or $e=5$.

---

Edit: problem solved by the comments!

Comment: If $n$ is even, then $p\equiv 2,4\pmod 5$.  If $n$ is odd, then $p\equiv 2\pmod 3$.  In no case can we get  $p\equiv 3\pmod 5$.

Comment: Does $\Bbb Z_p=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$?

Comment: $p\equiv 3 \pmod 5$ implies $5 \mid 2^n$.

Comment: $2^n+2$ is divisible by $3$ if and only if $n$ is even and divisible by $5$ if and only if $n$ is of the form $4k+3$. Hence $p$ cannot be of the form $3k+1$ AND of the form $5k+1$. The claim is also true for $n=1$, hence it is always true.

Comment: @samerivertwice: yes. Sorry, I was raised on that notation, and it comes out of my fingers even though a part of me is convinced that I should not.